# Simple system like git for storaging binary files (almost only jpeg,jpg,mp3,mp4) for personal using LOCALLY. Binary files change never, only are added

Tags: git, version-control

I wanna make a system for storaging my personal data like photos and videos. It's like diary. It uses Obsidian for notes and links between notes and other data like photo and video. It's saved in my computer and I've made backup by hand. It's a good idea to use Git for automatization this process. I wrote simple scripts like:

make_patch.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 <first_commit_hash>"
  exit 1
fi

first_commit_hash=$1

git format-patch $first_commit_hash --stdout --binary > patch
```

apply_patch.sh

```
git am --committer-date-is-author-date patch
```

get_hash.sh

```
echo $(git rev-parse HEAD)
```

After adding new photos or notes to main repo, I make a commit. If I want to synchronize two repos, I use get_hash.sh for repo with old story and provide it to make_patch.sh and then apply with apply_patch.sh. But it's also not so good. Yeah, I can make more automatizaion just by providing path from one repo to another, but there are also other problems like:

Using just Git consumes double memory than without it. If folder with some data requires X memoty, git repo with commited the same folder requires 2X memory. But I only add new binary data, I never change saved photos and videos (but I can change text files).
There also a lot of extra movements like making patches. But my backup repo is just on another SSD disk, which I can connect to my computer with USB.

So there are several questions:

1. The main question: Which tool or syster or anything should I use in order to keep my Git repo part's (of binary files) size as almost the same as a just folder? I mean, without double increase of memory for binary data.
2. Is it possible to decrease count of movements for synchronizing two branch in 2 local Git repos?

I checked a little documentation of git-lfs but it seems to me that it's not my case.

Comment: Are you sure Git isn't the tool for this job?  I suspect you may be double-counting files that are linked to two directories.

Comment: Nope, just try to create a directory with one file and then make a Git repo there. Check size of the directory before and after, you'll see that the size increases double

Comment: Git LFS may help, as that's the job it's designed for.  But I haven't used it myself.